$a_{n+1}$ is the greatest prime factor of $a_n^2+1.$ Does $a_n\to\infty$ for any starting integer $a_1?$
This is vaguely related to the Collatz conjecture in flavour, in the sense that it is to do with integer sequences that may loop or go to infinity.
Let $a_1$ be a positive integer and let $a_{n+1}$ be the greatest prime factor of $a_n^2+1$.
Of course, $(a_n)$ is not necessarily increasing. In fact, it may even be the case that there is no $a_1$ that produces a sequence which is strictly increasing. However, based on numerical evidence, it seems that

$a_n\to\infty$ for any starting value $a_1.$ In other words, there are no "loop sequences".

For example,
$1\to 2\to 5\to 13\to 17\to 29\to 421\to 401\to 53\to 281\to 3037\to 70949\to 1713329\to 1467748131121 \to ? $
Is this blockquote known to be true (with proof), or is there a counter-example loop, or is this an open problem?
It's possible this is a duplicate question, although I looked and didn't find it.

@CalvinLin I do not know any that go off to infinity. One important question is basically asking, "can you prove that there exists such a sequence (or disprove)? I will put the sequence starting with $a_1=1$ in the body of the question soon, although part of the problem is that I do not have resources to calculate factors of very large numbers.

@AdamRubinson Is the claim in the blockquote actually a quote that you found somewhere?  If so, then please cite the source.  If instead it is your statement, then please provide the numerical evidence.

This is a problem I came up with just now. I will say that I suspect it is a duplicate, because I feel like I have seen this exact question, or a very similar one before (although it was a while ago). But I may be mistaken about this.

The sequence starting with $1$ is A031439 - there is a question from 2006 asking whether it tends to infinity.

$a_1=34, a_2=89,a_3=233,a_4=89,\ldots$

If we set $a_1 = 89$, then $a_1^2+1 = 89^2+1 = 7922 = 2 \cdot 17 \cdot 233$, so $a_2 = 233$.
Then, $a_2^2+1 = 233^2+1 = 54290 = 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 61 \cdot 89$, and so $a_3 = 89 = a_1$.
Hence, for $a_1 = 89$, the sequence alternates between $89$ and $233$.

EDIT (a few more initial values that get stuck in cycles): Davide Masi made the interesting observation below that many starting values $a_1$ for which the sequence eventually alternates between $89$ and $233$ are Fibonacci numbers. Fibonacci numbers ($F_0 = 0$, $F_1 = 1$, $F_{n+1} = F_n+F_{n-1}$) satisfy the following properties:

If $n$ is odd, then $F_n^2 + 1 = F_{n-2}F_{n+2}$.

If $n$ is even, then $F_n^2 + 1 = F_{n-1}F_{n+1}$.

If $m \mid n$, then $F_m \mid F_n$.

If $n \ge 3$, then $F_{n-1} \ge \dfrac{1}{3}F_{n+1}$ and $F_{n-2} \ge \dfrac{1}{8}F_{n+2}$


Now, let $\mathcal{F}(N)$ denote the largest prime factor of $N$. If $F_p$ and $F_{p+2}$ are prime for some odd $p \ge 6$, and $p+4$ is divisible by some integer $q \in [6,p]$ (so that $8 \le F_q \le F_p$), then, we have:

$\mathcal{F}(F_{p-2}^2 + 1) = \mathcal{F}(F_{p-4}F_p) = F_p$,

$\mathcal{F}(F_{p-1}^2 + 1) = \mathcal{F}(F_{p-2}F_p) = F_p$

$\mathcal{F}(F_p^2 + 1) = \mathcal{F}(F_{p-2}F_{p+2}) = F_{p+2}$

$\mathcal{F}(F_{p+1}^2 + 1) = \mathcal{F}(F_pF_{p+2}) = F_{p+2}$

$\mathcal{F}(F_{p+2}^2 + 1) = \mathcal{F}(F_pF_{p+4}) = \mathcal{F}\left(F_{p} \cdot F_q \cdot \dfrac{F_{p+4}}{F_q}\right) = F_p$

$\mathcal{F}(F_{p+3}^2 + 1) = \mathcal{F}(F_{p+2}F_{p+4}) = \mathcal{F}\left(F_{p+2} \cdot F_q \cdot \dfrac{F_{p+4}}{F_q}\right) = F_{p+2}$


Thus, we can establish the following sequences that get stuck alternating between $F_p$ and $F_{p+2}$:



$a_1$
$a_2$
$a_3$
$a_4$




$F_{p-2}$
$F_p$
$F_{p+2}$
$F_p$


$F_{p-1}$
$F_p$
$F_{p+2}$
$F_p$


$F_{p}$
$F_{p+2}$
$F_{p}$
$F_{p+2}$


$F_{p+1}$
$F_{p+2}$
$F_{p}$
$F_{p+2}$


$F_{p+2}$
$F_p$
$F_{p+2}$
$F_p$


$F_{p+3}$
$F_{p+2}$
$F_{p}$
$F_{p+2}$



Based on the Wikipedia article for Fibonacci Prime, $F_{431}$, $F_{433}$, $F_{569}$, and $F_{571}$ are prime. Also, $435 = 15 \cdot 29$ and $573 = 3 \cdot 191$. So an initial value of $a_1 \in \{F_{429}, F_{430}, F_{431}, F_{432}, F_{433}, F_{434}\}$ will result in the sequence alternating between $F_{431}$ and $F_{433}$, and an initial value of $a_1 \in \{F_{567}, F_{568}, F_{569}, F_{570}, F_{571}, F_{572}\}$ will result in the sequence alternating between $F_{569}$ and $F_{571}$.
Note: For $p = 11$, we also have the $6$ sequences in the table above which get stuck alternating between $F_{11} = 89$ and $F_{13} = 233$. However, it takes a slightly different argument to check that $F_{15} = 610 = 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 61$ decomposes into primes $\le F_{11} = 89$. Also, it is quite possible for non-Fibonacci numbers $a_1$ to result in a sequence that gets stuck in a cycle. And it might be possible for that cycle to be between non-Fibonacci numbers, but I haven't found any.

Well done. How did you find that so quickly? Brute force (breadth-first search)?

I wrote a short MATLAB script to loop over initial values $a_1$.

Do you think there might be other counterexamples, or this one is unique?

@o.spectrum Good question. I managed to check that for every initial value $a_1 \le 3\times 10^5$, there exists a $k \le 100$ such that either $a_k > a_1$ or $a_k \in {89,233}$. But of course, it is entirely possible that there exists an initial value $a_1 \le 3 \times 10^5$ which results in a sequence that grows first and then shrinks and then gets stuck in another loop besides the $89$ and $233$ loop.

@JimmyK4542 Apparently, by running a small script, I found that for any $a_1\in{34, 55, 89, 123, 144, 233, 322, 377, 411, 500, 568, \dots}$ the sequence starts to alternate between $89$ and $233$.  I have also seen some of the other "fake" decreasing sequences, the longest of which probably was ${73, 41}$, but I only checked first 4 sequence elements for the first $10^3$ initial values.

@JimmyK4542 I wonder your MATLAB script. It will be interesting!

@o.spectrum it's interesting that many of them are Fibonacci numbers: $34,55,89,144,233,377$. I wonder if that's just a coincidence

Thanks for the mention and your impressive work!

Also, I have just observed that the other values of $a_1$ found by @o.spectrum are also sum of (non consecutive) Fibonacci numbers: $123 = 89+34, 322 = 233 + 89, 411 = 377 + 34, 500 = 411 + 89$. $568$ is an exception, apparently.
